# tflite model encryption for android

Tags: android, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I recently made a small android app, having a tensorflow model(tflite) in it. The tflite model is inside the assests folder and I think it is not a good practice to directly put the model, as some different apps are saving their models in .dat format. So can anyone help in converting the tflite model to .dat format or any other relevant encryption technique.

Answer (score 0):

`.tflite` format is the standard approach to serving mobile models. I'm not sure what particular format you mean by ".dat" but perhaps this is the output of someone's encryption technique. [Here is one approach](https://github.com/dneprDroid/TFSecured) to encrypting a Tensorflow file.

If you are worried about the confidentiality of your model in storage, another approach would be to host it online and load the model from the network. Look at [TensorFlow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving) for a production model deployment API.

You might also ind this SO discussion on [Keras model encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61248669/2202359) helpful.

Comment: This does not help for TfLite. The first URL concerns regular Tf, not TfLite. The second URL does not tell anything about encryption. The third URL is already given in the discussion of your first URL.