# Share a 'limited' version of a keras/.h5 model offline

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I have created a MLP keras model thats been saved in `.h5` format. I would like to share this .h5 model with someone else, but have 2 problems:

1. I don't want this other person to have 'unlimited' use to my model. I want them to be able to fully utilize it, but only for a limited amount of time.
2. The other person using this model is very sensitive about the inputs/predictions that they will use/get from my model, and do not want to upload their sensitive data online.

Is it possible to have a mechanism that solves both of the above problems? I've looked at ways of hosting this model via a simple web app, but nothing seems to be secure enough to get around problem #2.

Is there a known solution to this?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61245326/how-to-hide-or-encrypt-my-own-keras-model-filelike-h5-when-deploying